# How can I get an XQuery map of MarkLogic document URIs to lexicon (range index) values in the document?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm writing a REST API extension where I need to know the mapping of lexicon values to documents.

Given a lexicon (and backing range index), how can I get a map of of document URIs to lexicon (index) values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XQuery, for values of an element, use

```
cts:value-tuples(cts-uri-reference(), cts:element-reference("foo"))
```

For values of a field, use:

```
cts:value-tuples(cts-uri-reference(), cts:field-reference("foo"))
```

See also

```
cts:collection-reference, 
cts:element-attribute-reference, 
cts:path-reference, 
cts:geospatial-attribute-pair-reference
cts:geospatial-element-child-reference
cts:geospatial-element-pair-reference
cts:geospatial-element-reference
cts:geospatial-path-reference
```

You can get a map on co (or n-way) occurence tuples as well, by providing more arguments to [cts:value-tuples()](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts%3avalue-tuples).

Comment: If you want the results in `map:map` format, don't forget the 'map' option.

Comment: @eric-bloch: can one also use value-tuples to do the inverse? Find all uris/docs that doesn't have element foo?